# double quotes at end of concatenated TSQL string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In the following concatenated TSQL string, it is apparent that the single quotes separate the literal part of the string from the variables, but the double quotes at the end of the string perplexes me since the pattern seems to be N' to denote the literal pieces.  I don't see an explanation for this although I know there is one?

```
SET @ntsql = N'SELECT * INTO sdMembership FROM '
    + @BackupName
    + @BackupDate
    + N' WHERE FiscalYear = '
    + CAST(@FiscalYear AS VARCHAR(4))
    + N''
```

Comment: I would imagine it helps with readability and maintainability.

Comment: Have you neted any difference in how the variable is set if you remove the last part? It really doesn't seem to do anything since it concatenates an empty string.

Comment: the `N` just indicates that it's an `nvarchar` string

Comment: [Why do we need to put N before strings in Microsoft SQL Server?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/155859/why-do-we-need-to-put-n-before-strings-in-microsoft-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just an nchar empty string at the end
Pretty sure it does nothing
The null is to show you empty string is not the same as null

```
select null as [dbnull], N'ldkjf' as [string], len(N'ldkjf') as [len]

select null as [dbnull], N'' as [empty_string], len(N'') as [len]
```

And for clarity don't use the term double quote as that is a character.
It is two single quotes.

Comment: Yes, the string at the end does nothing.  I took it from another example where they had it in place probably for readability.